# How to load compressed files into BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to upload the wikipedia pageviews from http://dumps.wikimedia.org/other/pagecounts-raw/ into BigQuery, what's the fastest way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a classic demo I do to show how easy is to load data into BigQuery.

To get an hour of pageviews from Wikipedia, just wget the file:

```
wget http://dumps.wikimedia.org/other/pagecounts-raw/2014/2014-06/pagecounts-20140602-180000.gz
```

Then load it into BigQuery (should take less or around 5 minutes):

```
bq load -F" " --quote "" fh-bigquery:wikipedia.pagecounts_20140602_18 pagecounts-20140602-180000.gz language,title,requests:integer,content_size:integer
```

Note that this file weights around 100MB compressed (gz), and you don't need to decompress files this size to load them into BigQuery. It contains around 8 million rows of hourly pageviews counts.

- `-F" "`: This file is separated by spaces, not comma.
- `--quote ""`: This file doesn't use quotes for strings.
- fh-bigquery:wikipedia.pagecounts_20140602_18: The name of the BigQuery dataset where the file will be loaded.
- pagecounts-20140602-180000.gz: The name of the gz file downloaded from wikimedia.
- `language,title,requests:integer,content_size:integer`: The columns. By default everything is loaded as a string, except when we explicitly cast it to a different type (integers in this case).

(Requires previous installation of the [bq tool](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/bq-command-line-tool-quickstart))

I made this dataset public, you can find this table at https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/table/fh-bigquery:wikipedia.pagecounts_20140602_18.

I also left all the August pageviews at https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/table/fh-bigquery:wikipedia.wikipedia_views_201308 (53 billion pageviews if you `SELECT SUM(requests) FROM [fh-bigquery:wikipedia.wikipedia_views_201308]`.

Comment: Felipe, does this work with `.zip` files? I tried to upload one, but it returned an error. Unzipped `csv` did fine. Also, how does BQ handle multiple compressed files in a single archive?

Comment: For compression, only .gz (gzip) files will work - so multiple compressed files are not an option (.gz doesn't handle that either)